# attr_accessible on create only in Rails 3.2 and up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there way to say in Rails model that the attribute is accessible only if creating new record but when updating not?

something like:

```
class DesiredModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :type, :only => [:create]   # this is just example
   attr_accessible :type if :new_record?       # this is just example
end
```

Comment: Do you want to prevent the attribute to be both written and read after the object was created?

Answer (score 2):

The `attr_accessible` can't be parameterized this way. However you can add a role like condition with `:as => :create`. This way you can mass allow mass assignment on this field, by adding the role to it.

```
attr_accessible :type, :as => :create

...

model.assign_attributes(params[:model], :create)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use attr_readonly. It allows you to set the attribute value but it ignores the attribute when you update the record. If you call reload on the model after updating, you will see the attribute is still the same.